# React TypeScript Props Interface for string

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass the `title` down to the child Modal component

```
<Modal title='Register'/>
```

`const Modal` has the error

> Type '(props: PropsWithChildren) => { props: PropsWithChildren; (Missing): any; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
>     Type '{ props: PropsWithChildren; (Missing): any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)>': type, keyts(2322)

```
import React from 'react';

interface propsInterface {
    title: string; 
}

const Modal: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {
  return (
    {props.title}
  );
}

export {Modal};
```

Comment: `return props.title` or wrap with div tag like this `return <div>{props.title}</div>`

Comment: Try this `return <>{props.title}</>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just forgotten to return `jsx`

```
const Modal: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {
  return (
    props.title
  );
}
```

OR

```
const Modal: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {
  return (
    <span>{props.title}</span>
  );
}
```